# Element type is invalid: expected a string, using JSX to define a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just following some basic guides and got issues already. I can't see the problem with the below code but i'm getting the error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
> Check the render method of `Navbar`.

Can someone point where i'm going wrong please? Will use server side rendering some point but for now i'm just trying to get the design and layout done.

```
// _app.tsx

import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import '../styles/globals.css';

import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

```
// index.tsx

import type {NextPage} from 'next'

const Home: NextPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
                Header
            </h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

```
// Layout.jsx

import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Head from "next/head";

const Layout = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />

            <div className="bg-background h-full">
                <Head>
                    <title>Test</title>
                </Head>

                <main>
                    {children}
                </main>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default Layout
```

```
// Navbar.jsx

import Link from "next";

function Navbar() {
    return (
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">About</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">Menu</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">Gallery</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
export default Navbar
```

Comment: should not you be importing `next/link` instead of `next` ?
`https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link` ?

Comment: Ah damn! My mistake, I allowed my IDE to do the import and didn't notice it was incorrect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct your Link import

```
import Link from "next/link";
```